# Which 433MHz transmitter module can be used for battery operated wireless communication having vey low current consumption (less than 5mA)

Tags: rf, transmitter

Im designing a wireless water level controller. The WLC detects water between overhead and underground tank. The transmitter will be situated at each of the tanks. After water level sensing , the signal will be fed to encoder IC which transmits data through transmitter. Ive searched many transmitter modules. Most of them has a current consumption ranging from 9 - 40 mA. However such a large current consumption will drain the battery in 5-6 days. Ill be using 2 AA batteries of 1.5V each. Hence it is required to have a current consumption less than 5 mA. Ive researched that OOK modulation can be used for low power consumption. But im unable to understand how to implement it. Please let me know how can i implement the transmission of signal at a distance of 100-200m at 433MHz frequency. Also using arduino is not a feasible option for multiple tanks As it'll require uisng in each transmitter circuit

Comment: Turn it off 99% of the time, and it will last 500-600 days.

Comment: You seem to want to push the technology to the max. You have some reasonable distance there. I want to back the @user253751 proposal of collecting data, powering the transmitter, sending data and turning off. It seems, you don't need 2-way communication, so no problem with that. Besides, I thought for a moment, maybe you could implement little solar panel to charge the battery of the transmitter. By the way, you can also transmit battery level too! Like your transmitter sends "water level 1m, battery 20%"

Comment: @Ilya You're suggesting that if the transmitter requires a 3.3V supply then i should develop a logic to give 3.3V to the VCC pin of transmitter only when i need to send the signal ? Also can you suggest the method by which ill be able to transmit battery level ? Also on the receiver side i'll be connecting the output of Decoder (HT12D) to a relay coil which will turn on the motor (1HP) which in turn will pump the water from lower tank to upper tank. Thank you for your response

Comment: 1) Yes, if it's transmitter, it only sends data. If you don't send any data, why to power it all all. 2) If you can measure it, you can transmit it, right? I mean, you measure it with ADC (don't know if there's one in ESP), and then transmit the value, probably as a binary, then on the host side you just convert it to voltage value.